# byte array to hexa string for CRC use

Tags: python, crc, crc16

I need to know how can we convert a byte array like this one for example input =[0x6E,0x00,0x00,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x2F,0x4A,0x0,0x00] to an hexadecimal string '\x6E\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00' because i need to use it to calculate my CRC like that binascii.crc_hqx(b'\x6E\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00',0) . is their any function that allow me to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `bytes()` function:

```
binascii.crc_hqx(bytes([0x6E,0x00,0x00,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x2F,0x4A,0x0,0x00]), 0)
```